# Can't upload image to wordpress hosted on bigrock window server

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, server

I am trying to upload images for pages/post/gallery in wordpress customized theme. But it is giving me the below error.

```
“unnamed (1).png” has failed to upload due to an error
 The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2015/02.
```

I have tried chmod 777 but no luck.
Its hosted on bigrock window's server. Any pointers what i am missing.

Comment: give 777 permission to folder and subfolder

Comment: @Bugfixer already tried chmod 777 from filezila

Answer (score 1):

On our server we have an issue where the owner and group can get screwed up in plesk and cause these kinds of issues.  Even though you've changed the permissions, the owner (ftp owner, such as Wordpress) might still not have the ability to create/modify directories.

We have to login to the domain root via ssh (ssh user@domain.com) and reset the owner/group to the FTP user / group user for the domain using the following command:

```
chown -R username:psacln /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/
```

Update ‘username:psacln’ where the username is the actual ftp username (psacln is I believe Plesk's username for the group).
Update ‘/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/’ in the full path, to the domain name you are using (we use shared hosting which is why the path is a bit more complex).